# C# Sorting Type hierarchy

Tags: c#, reflection

I have multiple Types stored in a list, and I need to have them sorted from the most concrete type to the most general ones, example:

```
Vehicle
  Car
  Bike

Person
  Manager
  Programmer
```

So it makes list with: Vehicle, Car, Bike, Person, Manager, Programmer types. Now I need to get ordered list where more concrete type is always before more general type like: Car, Bike, Vehicle, Manager, Programmer, Person. Is there some simple/elegant way to achieve this, besides some gymnastics with Type.IsAssignableFrom ?

Comment: So sorting by priority essentially? vehicle = 1, car, bike = 2. Person = 1, manager, programmer =  2?

Comment: How would you sort between `Vehicle` and `Person`? Why does `Vehicle` come first in your example result?

Comment: Are you aware of Type.BaseType (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.basetype(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: ...and when you have base type then a (simplified) **topological sorting** will do the rest.

Comment: Preston + Adriano are correct. [Topological sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) using BaseType for the edges is the right answer here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One simple way is to figure that every child class must have more classes in its hierachy than its parents do, so you can order by how many classes are in each type's hierarchy:

```
var types = new[] {
    typeof(Vehicle),
    typeof(Car),
    typeof(Bike),
    typeof(Person),
    typeof(Manager),
    typeof(Programmer)
};
var ordered = types.OrderByDescending(t => GetHierarchy(t).Count());
```

Using this:

```
private static IEnumerable<Type> GetHierarchy(Type type)
{
    while (type != null) {
        yield return type;
        type = type.BaseType;
    }
}

class Vehicle {}
  class Car : Vehicle{}
  class Bike : Vehicle{}

class Person {}
  class Manager : Person{}
  class Programmer : Person{}
```

Comment: Seems like simple quick solution, that could be optimized if needed, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As Adam Pointed and also Jashaszun said, you need a common field that sets the priority of the type class, because Car and Bike are both at the same level in inheritance and you have to decide which has the highest priority.

In this case if you have all classes in the same collection and the classes can inherit from different root types (vehicle or person)
You can define an interface IPrioritySort with a Property Priority Integer and set the value for each different class (it can be a static if it is the same for all objects of a certain type) and use it to sort your collection.

It would be nice if you explain what you will achieve with this to understand if the solution is what we thought or if there is something else.